# Sorting lists based on very specific criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I am looking to sort a list based on if there is a "." there will be 2 items in the list, I just need to make sure it is in the correct format.

My list needs to be in the format: [item1, item2.ext]

I need the item without the extension (The folder) to be first to properly use shutil.

I know I could do 2 for loops through my list but that seems wasteful, and I know I could check to see weather or not I am pointing to a file or a folder but I think it is easier to force the list to be in the correct order explicitly.

Here is my code:

```
# Sets up a list of files and a blank list of those to remove
files = os.listdir(currentDir)
print(files)
files_to_remove = []
print(files_to_remove)

# Loops through files looking for
for f in files: # I could break this into 2 for loops but that seems dumb
    if "." not in f: #checks if is a folder
        files_to_remove.append(f)
        print(files_to_remove)
    if f"lecture{lecturenum}.zip" in f: #Checks if is the zip file that was just unzipped
        files_to_remove.append(f)
        print(files_to_remove)

print(files_to_remove)
time.sleep(0.1) # This removes a synching error where windows is trying to delete it while it is still using it
shutil.rmtree(currentDir + files_to_remove[0]) # I could change this to check before deciding

os.remove(currentDir + files_to_remove[1])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should probably use `os.path.isfile()` and `os.path.isdir()` to find out whether a path refers to a file or a directory, instead of looking at dots.

Comment: PSA: A folder name can contain a `.` (at least on Windows)

Comment: alternatively you can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) which make the separation of folder and non-folder for you, otherwise you're better of using `os.path.isfile` and/or `os.path.isdir` to differentiate between the two because there no rule in any operating system I know of that stop you from including a dot in a folder name